# Using MSSQL database types aliases, jooq 3.7.3 converted them to the proper Java type, but 3.12.3 converts them all to java type Object

Tags: java, sql-server, alias, jooq

For example, I have a database type alias defined as follows:

`create type aml_acct from varchar(50) not null`

Then in the SQL for creating a table, I would have a column definition like this:

```
create table ACCOUNTS (
  .   
  acct aml_acct,
  .
)
```

In 3.7.3 the Jooq generated code was this:

```
public final TableField<AmlAccountsRecord, String> ACCT = 
   createField("acct", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.VARCHAR.length(50).nullable(false), this, "");
```

In 3.12.3 the Jooq generated code is this:

```
    /**
     * @deprecated Unknown data type. Please define an explicit {@link org.jooq.Binding} to specify how this type should be handled. Deprecation can be turned off using {@literal <deprecationOnUnknownTypes/>} in your code generator configuration.
     */
    @java.lang.Deprecated
    public final TableField<AmlAccountsRecord, Object> ACCT = createField(DSL.name("acct"), org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.OTHER.nullable(false), this, "");
```

But I can't figure out how to make a Binding class to make this properly handle the `aml_acct` database type and generate the code as before. Or is there a way to handle this with a `ForcedType`?

Any ideas or help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

#### A bug in jOOQ

This is a bug in the jOOQ 3.12 code generator (probably also present in previous releases). Recent releases of the jOOQ code generator have added support for table valued functions and table valued parameters in SQL Server. For that, new `SYS` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` queries have been written to fetch meta data for SQL Server's code generation. In this case, `SYS.ALL_COLUMNS` is joined to `SYS.TYPES` on the `USER_TYPE_ID` column rather than the `SYSTEM_TYPE_ID` column.

This will be fixed in 3.13.0 and 3.12.4: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9551.

#### Workaround

The workaround is to use a `<forcedType>` configuration to force the type of your columns to the wanted data type:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/

For example:

```xml
<forcedType>
  <name>VARCHAR</name>
  <includeTypes>aml_acct</includeTypes>
</forcedType>
```

If you have many such types, you can also use `<sql>` in the above configuration to match all the columns that should have this forced type applied. This could look as follows:

```xml
<forcedType>
  <name>VARCHAR</name>
  <sql>
    select string_agg(o.name + '\.' + c.name, '|')
    from sys.all_objects o
    join sys.all_columns c on o.object_id = c.object_id
    join sys.types u on c.user_type_id = u.user_type_id
    join sys.types t on u.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
    where u.is_user_defined = 1
    and t.name = 'varchar'
  </sql>
</forcedType>
```

See the above documentation link for details.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I’ll give the suggestion on ForcedTypes a go.